# Capitalize the first letter after a punctuation

Tags: python

For example, I have this sentence:

```
hello. my name is Jess. what is your name?
```

and I want to change it into:

```
Hello. My name is Jess. What is your name?
```

I came up with this code, but I have one problem with connecting everything back together

```
def main():
    name = input('Enter your sentence: ')
    name = name.split('. ')
    for item in name:
        print (item[0].upper() + item[1:], end='. ')
```

When I put in the sentence, it will return:

```
Hello. My name is Jess. What is your name?.
```

How can I stop the punctuation from appearing at the end of the sentence?
Also, what if I have a question in the middle, for example:

```
hi. what is your name? my name is Jess.
```

Answer (score 8):

This one is better solution

```
x = "hello. my name is Jess. what is your name?"
print( '. '.join(map(lambda s: s.strip().capitalize(), x.split('.'))))

output:
Hello. My name is jess. What is your name?
```

Comment: It makes the name `Jess` become lowercase. OP requested output be `Hello. My name is Jess. What is your name?`

Answer (score 2):

You can construct your string first, following the same procedure, and the showing the string, except the last two values (you also need to remove the last space):

```
def main():
    result = ""
    name = input('Enter your sentence: ')
    name = name.split('. ')
    for item in name:
        result += item[0].upper() + item[1:] + '. '
    print result[:-2]
```

Comment: or even better combine this with @AdamHughes answer

Comment: I don't know why when I did it like that, there's an Invalid syntax exception raised, specifically at the end=' .' part

Comment: Importantly, this solution doesn't make proper names internal to the sentences lowercase. A more general solution for all typical end-of-sentence punctuation can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63192453/8508004 .

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative (and may be as an over complication also), you can use `nltk`'s [Sentence Segmentation](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html#sentence-segmentation). Relying on [@J.F. Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800751/771848):

```
>>> import nltk.data
>>> 
>>> sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> 
>>> text = "hello. my name is Jess. what is your name?"
>>> 
>>> sentences = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
>>> sentences = [sent.capitalize() for sent in sentences]
>>> print(' '.join(sentences))
Hello. My name is jess. What is your name?
```

Why it is not as simple as splitting a string by `.`? Generally speaking, the problem with `.` is that it is not only serving as a sentence delimiter. It also can be a part of an acronym or mark abbreviations inside a sentence (think also about all of the `Mr.`, `Mrs.`, `Dr.` etc):

> Sentence segmentation is difficult because period is used to mark
>   abbreviations, and some periods simultaneously mark an abbreviation
>   and terminate a sentence, as often happens with acronyms like U.S.A.

Answer (score 0):

Am I overlooking the obvious or can you just right strip?

Ie before you output your string:

```
finalstring = string.rstrip('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution to similar question, you can read how the following codes works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48688182/5265414

```
   original_data = raw_input("Enter text: ")
    list = original_data.split(".")
    if original_data.endswith('.'):
        list.remove('')

    for w in list:
        stripper= w.strip().capitalize() +"."
        print stripper,
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across this [string.capsword](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.capwords) and found it useful.

```
import string
sentence = 'hello. my name is Jess. what is your name?' 
string.capsword(sentence, sep='. ')  # sep should be a dot and space
```