# Uppercasing letters after '.', '!' and '?' signs in Python

Tags: python, uppercase

I have been searching Stack Overflow but cannot find the proper code for correcting e.g.

```
"hello! are you tired? no, not at all!"
```

Into:

```
"Hello! Are you tired? No, not at all!"
```

Comment: Split the string at characters like `.`, `!` and `?`. Capitalize each resulting part. Join the parts back to one string. Ready.

Comment: @Elgaard> stackoverflow is neither a coding service nor a cooked code solution database. It is about helping each other solve precise issues encountered while solving a problem. So start coding by yourself, and if and when you have a specific issue, come back with a specific question.

Comment: @spectras... Wow great respond from you! Listen I am a student at DTU Denmark as an engineer (3rd semester), and started a Python course. I am not a pro like you, but I try to find information online. Already did alot of programming my self! Sorry to ruin your day.

Comment: @Elgaard> no ruining at all. Good luck with the training, and don't hesitate to ask [a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should you get stuck. The whole community will be eager to help when it feels questions are interesting. It's not about being a beginner, many beginners ask amazing questions, and countless "pros" ask bad questions. You might be interested in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3212865) as well (scroll down to “asking about homework"). Anyway, have fun with your class :).

Answer (score 7):

You can try this regex approach:

```
import re
re.sub("(^|[.?!])\s*([a-zA-Z])", lambda p: p.group(0).upper(), s)
# 'Hello! Are you tired? No, not at all!'
```

---

- `(^|[.?!])` matches the start of the string `^` or `.?!` followed by optional spaces;
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches letter directly after the first pattern;
- use lambda function to convert the captured group to upper case;

Answer (score 3):

1. Use regular expressions to split at punctuation characters
2. Join everything back with capitalized letters at the start of the sentences.

For example like this:

```
import re
text = 'hello! are you tired? no, not at all!'

punc_filter = re.compile('([.!?]\s*)')
split_with_punctuation = punc_filter.split(text)

final = ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in split_with_punctuation])
print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> Hello! Are you tired? No, not at all!
```

Answer (score 2):

capitalize() method makes all letters small except the first one.

More general variant is:

```
def capitalize(text):
    punc_filter = re.compile('([.!?;]\s*)')
    split_with_punctuation = punc_filter.split(text)
    for i,j in enumerate(split_with_punctuation):
        if len(j) > 1:
            split_with_punctuation[i] = j[0].upper() + j[1:]
    text = ''.join(split_with_punctuation)
    return text

text = "hello Bob! are you tired? no, not at all!"
capitalize(text)
```

Output:

```
'Hello Bob! Are you tired? No, not at all!'
```

Comment: Importantly, this solution doesn't make proper names internal to the sentences lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
x = "hello! are you tired? no, not at all!"
y = x.split("? ")
z="" 
for line in y:
    z = "{} {}".format(z,line.capitalize())
print(z)
```

And adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you RnRoger! :) I will try that.

Comment: np ^^. I didn't get it to work with multiple split characters though. (eg "?" AND "!")