# capitalizing the first letter in a text after split

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to capitalize the first letter of each word after "-" in a string and leave the rest of string intact?

```
x="hi there-hello world from Python - stackoverflow"
```

expected output is

```
x="Hi there-Hello world from Python - Stackoverflow"
```

what I tried is :

```
"-".join([i.title() for i in x.split("-")]) #this capitalize the first letter in each word; what I want is only the first word after split
```

Note: "-" isn't always surrounded by spaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize the first letter after a punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639677/capitalize-the-first-letter-after-a-punctuation)

Comment: @JimG. should I delete question, that question answer me

Comment: [title](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/title.html) returns the string in Title Case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
import re

x = "hi there-hello world from Python - stackoverflow"
y = re.sub(r'(^|-\s*)(\w)', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper(), x)

print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"-".join([i.capitalize() for i in x.split("-")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what @Milad Barazandeh did but another way to do it

- `answer = "-".join([i[0].upper() + i[1:] for i in x.split("-")])`