# Capitalizing letters using for in range loop

Tags: python, range, for-in-loop, capitalization

I'm trying to solve a problem where a for in range loop goes over a sentence and capitalises every letter following a ".", a "!" and a "?" as well as the first letter of the sentence. For example,

```
welcome! how are you? all the best!
```

would become

```
Welcome! How are you? All the best!
```

i've tried using the `len` function, but I'm struggling with how to go from identifying the placement of the value to capitalising the next letter.

Comment: If `i` is the index of the punctuation character, `i+2` is the index of the start of the next sentence. Does that help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capitalize the first letter of every sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800401/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-every-sentence)

Comment: maybe, change character/letter to upper case if it comes after `' '` , `,`, `!`, `.` characters

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a regex substitution using a callable. There are two cases for the substitution.

- The string starts with a lower: `^[a-z]`
- There is a `.`, `!` or `?` followed by space and a lower. `[.!?]\s+[a-z]`

In both cases you can just uppercase the contents of the match. Here's an example:

```
import re

capatalize_re = re.compile(r"(^[a-z])|([.!?]\s+[a-z])")

def upper_match(m):
    return m.group(0).upper()

def capitalize(text):
    return capatalize_re.sub(upper_match, text)
```

This results in:

```
>>> capitalize("welcome! how are you? all the best!")
Welcome! How are you? All the best!
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two hints:

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return zip(a, b)
... 
>>> list(pairwise([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
>>> list(enumerate("hello"))
[(0, 'h'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (3, 'l'), (4, 'o')]
```

These two functions will greatly help you in solving this problem.